# How to find currents in a mesh system with only current sources?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis

Could someone please give me a rundown of how to find the currents in this problem? There are only current sources available and I am not sure how to find the branch currents.

There are answers given in the textbook but no information on how to get there.

[image]

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: All sources are parallel to each other.

Comment: @DonFusili does that mean I could combine the sources to make, let's say a downward current source of 30 amps?

Comment: Let's say yes, would that solve your problem?

Comment: @DonFusili doing so I could potentially transform the source into a voltage source, find the voltage for the parallel branches and then find each current. Let me try this out

Comment: @DonFusili Thank you for your help. I have found correctly i2 to i5, though I am still struggling with i1. I have recorded a total current (which should be i1) of 20 amps, but the answer indicates 10 amps. Any ideas on how this could be?

Comment: @Hammi1 I1 cannot be 20A, as I5 must be *larger* and you only have 30A altogether.

Comment: @TurboJ the total resistance is 36 ohms, which means the current going through the parallel branches must add up to 20, and the current going through the 24 ohm resistor in series should also be 20.il I know this is a wrong answer but I am not sure why

Comment: @Hammi1 why would the total current be I1? The total current comes from your current source and then splits into all the branches.

Comment: @Arsenal if I convert the 30 amp source into a 720 volt voltage source by combining with 24 ohm resistor, then the total resistance is 36 and current is 20 amps. In the parallel branches this also adds up because of KCL. Thus, the i1 going back into the voltage source is 20 amps.

Comment: I don't think you have done a valid transformation there - not all of the 30 A are flowing through the 24 ohm resistor.

Comment: @Arsenal its no longer 30 amps, it was only 30 amps for the current source, then converted into a voltage source using the 24 ohm resistor. The voltage source is now In series with the leftmost 24 ohm resistor, and the others are in parallel. The total resistance is 36 ohms, so the current going through the 2 branches at the end of the voltage source would be 20 amps. The 20 amps split up into the parallel branches on the right (which yields the correct answer) and will then go back to 20 amps because of KCL. Therefore the current going back into the voltage source, and thus I1, should be 20A

Comment: Don't you have to transform it back somehow if you want I1? I don't know on which basis you try to solve this, I have a slight memory of converting some sources around 10 years ago as I was studying but don't remember the details, I'll post how I would solve this - there are probably different approaches to this and I won't claim that mine is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approach I would take, which might not be the most efficient one and might not work for every circuit:

You already realized that all the current sources are in parallel and can be combined to a single one with 30 A. So the circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Hxyc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now I combine all of the resistors into a single equivalent one. I guess you know enough to do this, so here is the end result:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKqqlgm.png)</sup>

The equivalent resistance of all those resistors is 8 ohm. Now I can replace the current source by a voltage source of 240 V without changing the current in the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0zazl.png)</sup>

Just solving for the magnitudes:

I1 = 10 A (240 V / 24 ohm)

I2 = 8 A (240 V / (24 ohm + (24 ohm || 8 ohm)))

I3 = 6 A ((240 V - 8 A * 24 Ohm) / 8 ohm)

I4 = 2 A (8 A - 6 A)

I5 = 12 A (240 V / 20 ohm)

Be careful of course with the direction of the currents for a correct answer. The way they are drawn defines the sign convention for that current.

Comment: I think I understand now. I combined it with only one resistor and made that power source, instead of the rest of the resistors. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I'm wondering a bit if your approach couldn't be used as well if you got all the currents right but not the one (I1) remaining. I mean with the information that R2, R3, R4 and R5 are taking 20 A total, and you transfer it back to the first circuit, I1 must be 10 A as well - so I guess there is a different way to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

Redraw the circuit as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa2IFQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On further simplification:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJl5Xm.png)</sup>

if R = \$\frac{(R_2\times R_3)}{(R_2+R_3)} = 12 \Omega \$,
then using current divider formula:

$$I_1 = -I\times \frac{R}{(R+R1)} = -10 A$$
Similarly you will get \$I_5 = +12A\$ and therefore \$I_2 = -30 - I_1 + I_5 = -8 A\$
From the circuit its clear that, by KCL:
$$I_2 = I_4 - I_3$$
Using current divider formula again, we will get
$$I_4 = I_2\times \frac{8}{24+8} = -2 A $$
therefore \$I_3 = -2 + 8 = +6 A\$

I think I know where you went wrong.

**Source transformation:**

Consider this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxZD5B.png)</sup>

Its obvious that current through R1 = **4A** and R2 = **6A**

Suppose you transformed the current source with R1, across points A and B as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0d3AZ.png)</sup>

Using this resulting circuit, you can calculate only the current through the ***external circuit*** of the equivalent voltage source**, i.e., whatever is at the right side of A and B. You can calculate the current across R2, $$ I = 60/10 = 6 A$$ Which is the same as we obtained before in the original circuit.

But if you try to calculate the current through R1, which is internal to the voltage source, you will get it wrong as **6A**. We have already found that it is **4A**.

That is why you got it as **20A** for I1 after source transformation. You can calculate currents only in the external circuit, after source transformation.

Comment: Just got it. Thank you very much for giving the example, I now understand it properly.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking of, was just under 10 years of brain dust. Instead of saying "We have already found that it is 4A" (because we actually don't, your example was just obvious) you could go back and solve the circuit now in the non-transformed world.